# Programmatically get Azure VM Image Blob URI

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I created a custom Azure VM image but am unable to find the image's blob URI, which I need to specify in a deployment template's scale set.

How can I find the image's blob URI given the name and resource group of the image using the Azure CLI?

Comment: Update my reply to make it clear, please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nancy, it makes sense but my particular issue relates to telling a scale set what image to use in a resource manager template, which I believe only accepts the image blob's URI.

Answer (score 1):

```
az vm show -g <resourceGroup> -n <vmName> -o json
```

Will show you all the VM's properties

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear, but I'm trying to get information about a VM image, not a VM

Comment: What information specifically are you after?  Or what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to use an existing VM image (created w/ Packer) and spin up a scale set with that image.
The problem is that the scale set resource template asks for a URI to the image in a storage bucket rather than just the name of an image to use.

Comment: how was the original vm provisioned? (i.e. where did the original image come from?)

Answer (score 0):

If you [create a managed image of a generalized VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource). You can not get the Image URL since the image is managed by Azure. But you can get the source OsDisk VHD URL.

You can find the source OsDisk URL in the portal from the generalized VM---source OsDisk---Export---Generate URL, you will find the SAS URL for the OsDisk. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd). Or you can run the script with CLI to find the SAS URL.

```
az disk grant-access --duration-in-seconds 3600 --name $OsDiskname  --resource-group $resourcegroupname
```

Here is a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297321/how-can-i-get-the-url-of-a-captured-vm-image-stored-in-azure-resource-manager?rq=1) for your reference. Hope this helps.